# How to convert DataPackage to DataPackageView

Tags: uwp

I want to extract HTML content from WebView. So:

```
private async void WebViewFrame_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = await WebViewFrame.CaptureSelectedContentToDataPackageAsync();
    DataPackageView dataPackageView = dataPackage.GetView() as DataPackageView;
    string siteHTML = await dataPackageView.GetHtmlFormatAsync();
    Text.Text = siteHTML;
}
```

I get an error:
    System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in method `GetView()`

Comment: is `dataPackage` null?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the '**Remark**' section on the [WebView.CaptureSelectedContentToDataPackageAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.captureselectedcontenttodatapackageasync#remarks) document, it shows:

> This method is asynchronous, so you must use a deferral to prevent your [DataRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager.datarequested) event handler from returning before the asynchronous call is complete. Call [DataRequestedEventArgs.Request.GetDeferral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datarequest.getdeferral#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataRequest_GetDeferral) to create the deferral and [DataRequestDeferral.Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datarequestdeferral.complete#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataRequestDeferral_Complete) to end it.

But I have not saw that you use a deferral in your code. So please try it.

The official [Sharing content source app sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/ShareSource/cs/ShareHtml.xaml.cs#L36) is for your reference.